# ejs include function can not find the template with html extension

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

My ejs engine set up is app.js is like below:

```
// this parse html file as ejs file
    app.engine('.html', require('ejs').__express);
    app.set('view engine', 'html');
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/view');
```

My directory is like this:

```
view (folder)
  home.html
  head.html
app.js
```

Home.html is like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>home</title>
<% include head %>
</head>

<body>

</body>
</html>
```

and head.html is like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.5.js"></script>
```

the problem is the file head.html will not be parsed if the extension was html. Error says it expect ejs file. So there is a problem with include function?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As Elie Gnrd is suggesting, you use `.ejs` files directly by changing the `view engine` configuration of Express.

If that isn't an option, and you want/need to keep using `.html` as an extension for your templates, you have to be explicit in the include:

```
<% include head.html %>
```

Answer (score 2):

arrr ;)

1. you did not mention what app - so I assume Express >=3
2. solution : forget the dot and __express in

app.engine('.html', require('ejs').__express);

**It should read :**

```
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use .ejs files directly by using `app.set('view engine', 'ejs');` and renaming index.html to index.ejs.

Here is an example:
http://robdodson.me/blog/2012/05/31/how-to-use-ejs-in-express/

Comment: actually I want to use ejs engine but the file extension is html

Comment: app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

Answer (score 1):

I too had this problem and modified this file of my app:

```
myapp/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js
```

The function is:

```
function resolveInclude(name, filename) {
  var path = join(dirname(filename), name);
  var ext = extname(name);
  if (!ext) path += '.ejs';
  return path;
}
```

You can change the default extension or as in my case I changed the function to a more direct:

```
function resolveInclude(name, filename) {
  return join(dirname(filename), name) + '.html';
}
```

They can modify the function as they wish.

I hope that is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

change html file with ejs

```
   -view
   --home.ejs
   --head.ejs
   -app.js
```

set app view engine like

```
  app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

make index.ejs for main file and include home.ejs and head.ejs in index.ejs

```
<%- include('head')%>;
<%- include('home')%>;
```

and render it app.js like

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => { 
    res.render('index');
});
```

cmiiw..